# Como fazer um POST que passe além do formulário, um arquivo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Minha duvida é a seguinte: Eu consigo passar para o controller OU o arquivo OU o formulário. Eu queria saber se existe algum tipo (igual FormCollection, porém este aparentemente só recebe o formulário em si, os arquivos postados juntos não) que receba tanto o formulário quanto o arquivo em um POST só. Já pesquisei informações a respeito mas sempre é enviado o arquivo sozinho, e eu queria enviar junto com o formulário.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="nome"/>
<input type="text" name="Sobrenome"/>
<input type="file" id="FileUpload1" /> &nbsp;
<button id="btnEnviarArquivo" style="margin left:-6px;">Enviar Arquivo</button>
<button type="button" id="Enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Cadastro",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {

    }

});
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult Cadastro(FormCollection form)
{
     return Json(new {});
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você precisará implementar requisições do tipo `Multipart`, parte da especificação `HTTP 1.1`.

Para fins de demonstração, eu criei o seguinte *webform*, contendo campos de texto e um fileupload:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" (...)%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuja aparência, quando visualizado no Chrome, é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu interceptei o *payload* via Wireshark. Esta é a requisição enviada para o servidor:

```
POST /script/OpCenter/samplewebpart.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: [SERVER].[DOMAIN]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12373
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://[SERVER].[DOMAIN]
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryCYhgqEfRdnZkrdRf
Referer: http://[SERVER].[DOMAIN]/script/OpCenter/samplewebpart.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6

------WebKitFormBoundaryCYhgqEfRdnZkrdRf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATE"
/wEPDwULLTEwNjc5MDgzOTQPZBYCAgMPFgIeB2VuY3R5cGUFE211bHRpcGFydC9mb3JtLWRhdGFkZOW8eX8I0G+ceXPjDwfXA1MRJuxEFHvp1y5twOS3H9uw

------WebKitFormBoundaryCYhgqEfRdnZkrdRf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTVALIDATION"

/wEWAwLQ+p/sDwLs0bLrBgKM54rGBqByybWBtQAZmIHlcbrUlcixkQ/+JlgNypmZ4vFxAn6b
------WebKitFormBoundaryCYhgqEfRdnZkrdRf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="TextBox1"

teste
------WebKitFormBoundaryCYhgqEfRdnZkrdRf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileUpload1"; filename="Alert.png"
Content-Type: image/png

.PNG
....IHDR.............\r.f....gAMA....7.......tEXtSoftware.Adobe ImageReadyq.e<..,.IDATx..}y..wu......5..4:,....,..O..l.M.......q..5.\.%......;$..
(mais ou menos 12Kb depois...)
.f....`0...^..`0.0..&......`0.........`.`0.L.......`0.0..&......`0....F....0.p9.Xd..F....IEND.B`.

------WebKitFormBoundaryCYhgqEfRdnZkrdRf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Button1"

Button
------WebKitFormBoundaryCYhgqEfRdnZkrdRf--
```

(Perceba que mesmo os campos escondidos de controle de estado do ASP.NET, `__VIEWSTATE` e `__EVENTVALIDATION`, estão presentes no conteúdo *multipart*.)

Isso dito, vamos à solução do lado *client* usando jQuery e Ajax:

1) Prepare os dados a serem enviados, empacotando-os em uma instância da classe FormData

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
```

(Inclua, neste momento, todos os dados que precisar, incluindo os presentes no formulário, via `data.append`.)

2) Realize sua chamada Ajax, passando a instância de FormData como parâmetro:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'paginadestino.aspx',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Referências:

[Esta é uma maneira de implementar Multipart do lado client em uma chamada Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) (resposta aceita.)

[Este post tem um exemplo de como tratar multipart do lado do servidor (em C#).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277849/how-can-i-upload-data-and-a-file-in-the-same-post)

(As referências estão em inglês.)

Comment: E o tratamento no servidor como seria?

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma duvida que já tive há tempos atrás e pesquisando cheguei as seguintes respostas/conclusões:

Até onde meu conhecimento vai, atualmente a resposta é não, não é possível enviar dados de um formulário e um arquivo em uma mesma requisição para o servidor.

Digo atualmente, por que atualmente estamos utilizando [HTTP 1.1 (que é de 1995/1996)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), que não suporte esse tipo de requisição. Mas [SPDY (by Google)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) e [HTTP 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_2.0) (que é o novo padrão HTTP em desenvolvimento, e é baseado no SPDY), pretendem resolver essas limitações do HTTP 1.1.

> Mas apesar de já haverem servidores implementando esses novos padrões HTTP. Na garantem que esse tipo de suporte será mantido na versão final.

Comment: HTTP 1.1 suporta Content-Type: multipart/*, que seria em teoria o que ele precisa.

Comment: @OnoSendai, oohh, estava torcendo para ser desmentido, mas Content-Type `multipart/*` permite enviar uma imagem e um form em uma mesma requisição? E o servidor irá saber processar isso de forma fácil. Ou terá que ler toda a requisição de forma manual? Aguardarei sua resposta e depois removerei minha resposta (se for comprovada incorreta).

Comment: Resposta atualizada!

Answer (score 0):

Sim existe, para demostração fiz algumas alterações no seu form igual nas figuras ilustrativas logo abaixo, e os exemplos são para `WebForms` e `MVC` ***ASP.NET***.

***1 - MVC***

*View:*

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Upload</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Form1" id="Form1">
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /><br />
        <label>Sobrenome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" /><br />
        <label>Arquivo:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" /><br />        
        <button type="button" id="Enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Enviar").on("click", function () {
                var form = new FormData();
                $.each($("#Form1 #fileupload")[0].files, function(idx, file){
                    form.append("FileUpload", file);
                });
                form.append('Nome', $("#nome").val());
                form.append('SobreNome', $("#sobrenome").val());
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Upload")',
                    data: form,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Action Result:*

```
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(String Nome, String SobreNome, HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
{
    return View();
}
```

*Resultado esperado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

***2 - WebForms***

*ASPX*

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationForms.Upload" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Upload</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /><br />
        <label>Sobrenome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" /><br />
        <label>Arquivo:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" /><br />
        <button type="button" id="Enviar">Enviar</button>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#Enviar").on("click", function () {
                    var form = new FormData();
                    $.each($("#Form1 #fileupload")[0].files, function (idx, file) {
                        form.append("FileUpload", file);
                    });
                    form.append('Nome', $("#nome").val());
                    form.append('SobreNome', $("#sobrenome").val());
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Upload.ashx',
                        data: form,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data.Ok);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*Arquivo Upload.ashx (handler):*

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplicationForms
{    
    public class Upload1 : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            String Nome = context.Request.Form["Nome"].ToString();
            String SobreNome = context.Request.Form["SobreNome"].ToString();
            HttpPostedFile FileUpload = context.Request.Files["FileUpload"];

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {Ok = true}));
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Resultado esperado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]